# BS4 class with header tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.8

How would I parse a class to only get the text outside the header tag, or both in a list?

```
<div class="footballMatchSummaryDef"><h1>Burnley v Aston Villa</h1>English Premier League at Turf Moor</div>
```

I've considered using regex to extract but thought beautiful soup must be able t handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions, one is getting whole text and then split it according some separator:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="footballMatchSummaryDef"><h1>Burnley v Aston Villa</h1>English Premier League at Turf Moor</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

lst = soup.select_one('.footballMatchSummaryDef').get_text(separator='|').split('|')
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['Burnley v Aston Villa', 'English Premier League at Turf Moor']
```

---

Or using `bs4` navigation functions:

```
print( soup.h1.text )
print( soup.h1.find_next_sibling(text=True) )
```

Prints:

```
Burnley v Aston Villa
English Premier League at Turf Moor
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrej the navigation function was what I was after , works fine, only just started python so all new to me from php. It was the next sibling thing I needed

```
print( soup.h1.find_next_sibling(text=True) )
```